# Populate Treeview using Child_ID, Child_Name, Parent_ID, Parent_Name

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Good Day,

I am exporting a table from SQL Server into Access database from which I need to build a treeview and assign values to each nodes. I am bit newbie with treeview handling using VB .net.

The table structure is like this.

**Child_ID   ChildName  Parent_ID    ParentName    **

For each child object there is a Parent ID. 
Can any expert advise a way to populate treeview using above columns? During the process I want to assign ChildName/ParentName as the TreeNode text(displyName) and Child_ID/Parent_ID   as the treenode Tag which I want to use in another application.

Thanks in advance.

```
  RootName = "AppRootName" 

                            Dim root = New TreeNode(RootName)
                            MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(root)
                            MyTreeView.TopNode = root

                            For Each dbRow As DataRow In DTHier.Rows
                                ChildName = dbRow.Item(0).ToString()
                                ChildID = dbRow.Item(1).ToString().ToUpper  
                                ParentID = dbRow.Item(2).ToString().ToUpper
                                ParentName = dbRow.Item(3).ToString() 

                                Dim ParentNode = New TreeNode() With { _
                                   .Name = ParentName.ToString(), _
                                    .Text = ParentName, _
                                    .Tag = ParentID _
                               }

                                Dim ChildNode = New TreeNode() With { _
                                  .Name = ChildName.ToString(), _
                                   .Text = ChildName, _
                                   .Tag = ChildID _
                              }


                                MyTreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(ParentNode)

                                Dim NodeFound As Integer = MyTreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes.Find(ChildNode.Tag, True).Length
                                If NodeFound > 0 Then
                                    ParentNode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode)
                                End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try it:

```
  'Creating the root node
  ' Main Node - All Treeview MUST have at least ONE.
  Dim root = New TreeNode("Application")

  ' Add a node under it.
  TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)
  TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("First Child from Root"))

  'Creating child nodes under the first child
  For loopindex As Integer = 1 To 4
      TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Childs" & Str(loopindex)))
  Next loopindex

  ' creating child nodes under the root (0)
  TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Second Child from Root"))

  'creating child nodes under the created child node
  For loopindex As Integer = 1 To 3
      TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Childs from Node 1 - " & Str(loopindex)))
  Next loopindex
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try,

Comment: Hi David , I also have Depth attribute(Integer ) like 1,2, 3 etc. for each Child object with respect to its parent. Will that anyway help in building Treeview?  Kindly suggest.

Comment: I think you don´t need to utilize DEEP attribute. See the working sample above I don´t utilize it. The above sample works and set a name for each node, based on a string and a number.

Comment: Thanks. The bit I am struggling is how it will add a child-node only to its Parent node and not other Parent.  I will post the code I have done to give better understanding.. Update: Code posted in original Post... Pls advise. Thanks again.

Comment: See the last paragraph in my code above. You have to add the Child node within the selected node you choose before. You MUST put the node number before add, using that syntax:  Treeview.Node(0).Nodes(Parent).Nodes.Add.   You are creating childs nodes without referencing their parents.

Comment: Hi, I managed to sort it using a different approach. I am now populating only Top node and its children first. Then I populate children nodes for each Selected Node on MouseClick. I found this much faster. Thanks..

Comment: @DK2014, it´s a good procedure since you avoid dozens (or hundreds of nodes) be updated at once, wasting time. And if you consider I had helped you anyway, please vote. Thanks, best wishes and good luck.

Comment: Yes David. You answer definitely guided me in right direction. In my case, the data table may have rows more easily above 60-80K and growing more than 150-200K.. so the kind of on demand load of child nodes helps in faster performance & easier navigation..

Comment: Thanks @DK2014. I´m also happy of helped you some way. Good luck.